# Heketi operations not reflecting in glusterfs server

Tags: glusterfs

Started the two glusterfs server and able to create and mount volumes in two servers.

I have built heketi from [here](https://github.com/heketi/heketi.git) version 5.0.1. 
This is how I started the server from heketi after build.

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/heketi/heketi/
cp etc/heketi.json heketi.json
./heketi --config=heketi.json
```

The server started running on 8080

Now I am using the heketi client to interact with heketi server as follow

```
export HEKETI_CLI_SERVER=http://localhost:8080
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/heketi/heketi/client/cli/go
```

Added the topology.json with data in glusterfs server and able to run the following commands

```
./heketi-cli topology load --json=./topology.json
./heketi-cli volume create --size=1 --replica=2
./heketi-cli volume create --name=testvol --size=40 --durability="replicate" --replica=2
```

I am able to see the volumes created using heketi client. and also able to fetch all details of volume. But when I check the gluserfs server. I don't see any volumes created. Do anyone has idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://github.com/heketi/heketi/issues/956) for answer from community.

The example config file etc/heketi.json configures the mock executor which does not send commands to gluster at all and is used for testing purposes.

Please change this setting to ssh or kubernetes whichever applies to you (I assume ssh). You also have to fill the details of how to reach the gluster server with ssh (the settings under sshexec).